# Returning pointer to pointer parameter in C

Tags: c, pointers

I am wondering why the following two functions return different results:
The result of GetPtr is always NULL, whereas GetPtr2 returns a pointer to the parameter, the intended behavior.

```
#include <stdio.h>

unsigned char ** GetPtr(unsigned char *ptr)
{
    return &ptr;
}

unsigned char ** GetPtr2(unsigned char *ptr)
{
    unsigned char **ptr2 = &ptr;
    return ptr2;
}

int main()
{
    unsigned char *test = (unsigned char *) malloc(10 * sizeof(unsigned char));

    printf("%p \n", GetPtr(test));
    printf("%p \n", GetPtr2(test));

    free(test);

    return 0;
}
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Try this: "unsigned char ** GetPtr(unsigned char *ptr)    {    return *ptr;    }"

Comment: I want a pointer to the input pointer, I don't want to dereference it.

Comment: A pointer to the input pointer is useless since it's just a temporary copy pushed on the stack for the function call.

Comment: What does the program print?

Comment: If `GetPtr` is returning `NULL` for any input, the code you posted doesn't match what you're compiling. `GetPtr` can never return `NULL` as it's written above.

Comment: When I run this code, the result of both functions is the same (the address of the "temporary copy pushed on the stack" which is not useful).  Maybe I don't understand what you want, but why not just use the & operator?

Comment: @CareyGregory: The C standard does not mandate a stack for local variables. Don't even think in terms of stack/heap at this abstraction level.

Comment: @Olaf Well, fine, but the point remains that he's returning the address of a local variable that will be out of scope when the function returns.

Comment: @CareyGregory: Taking the address is fine, unless it is dereferenced.

Comment: @Olaf I know that, but what use is an address if it's not dereferenced? Returning the address of a local variable is simply a meaningless, dangerous thing to do.

Comment: Please provide **all** required inforrmation. This includes compiler, OS, target, etc.

Comment: Start with removind useless/potential harmful stuff like casting `void *` and `sizeof(unsigned char)`. You also don't include the declaration of `malloc` (or just by chance indirectly).

Comment: The `printf()`s are technically wrong, too, since you don't cast to `void *`, and `printf()` expects a `void *` with `%p`.

Answer (score 0):

```
unsigned char ** GetPtr(unsigned char *ptr)
{
    return &ptr;
}               // <-- scope of ptr ends here
```

You are using the address of an out-of-scope variable.  As the Monty Python skit had it, *It's an ex-parrot*.

This function returns the address of a local variable.  When  that address is received by the caller, the variable whose address it is will no longer be in scope.

Comment: How would `&ptr` ever result in NULL? It doesn't matter what the value of `ptr` is, it still had a non-null address when its address was taken.

Comment: @CareyGregory well I suppose that memory could have been overwritten by the time the printf statement is reached.

Comment: Please provide references to the standard. OP does not dereference the returned address, but only prints the returned value; there is no UB involved afais.

Comment: @IanM.: No, that is not possible, as you don't access any out-of-life value. I don't see a reason for this in your code.

Comment: @IanM. It is literally impossible for `&ptr` to be NULL. There is no circumstance where that can happen.

Comment: @CareyGregory and @Olaf, please consider that `&ptr` is *out of scope* when it's printed.  You're right that `&ptr` can't be NULL.  But by the time it reaches `printf`, it's the address of a nonexistent variable.  That's UB.  The compiler isn't obliged to keep that address around, and apparently this one doesn't.

Comment: @JamesK.Lowden: Again: Please provide reference why the returned value is invalid. OP does **not** dereference the pointer! It does not matter that the value does not point to valid memory, but the value itself very well is valid.

Comment: @JamesK.Lowden: It doesn't matter if `&ptr` is out of scope "when it is printed", because it's not actually being printed - the return value from `GetPtr()` is being printed, which certainly is in scope. `&ptr` is a perfectly valid pointer value at the point it is returned, and the returned value remains a perfectly valid pointer value. Whether or not it points to good memory is irrelevant, since it's not being dereferenced, as other commentators have said.

Comment: Returning the address of a local variable is not UB, and neither is printing that address. However, returning the address of a local variable is never useful and almost always an error, so the OP would do well to learn not to ever do that. And if he's seeing a value of NULL, then his code is incorrect and does not match what was posted here.

Comment: And FYI, one of the downvotes is mine. Delete your last paragraph and I'll remove my downvote. Ping me with a comment if you do so.

Comment: @CareyGregory, done.  Thank you for your persistence.  On reflection, the variable has a defined address and, as you say, the returned value of the function is in scope at the point of call.  It's no different than if the logic were `void *p = &ptr; return p;`.